# Issues connecting to a PostgreSQL container from inside a container

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, docker

I am having issues while trying to connect a docker container to a PostgreSQL container. The following exception is being thrown:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed
```

I am starting my containers through a docker-compose.yml, which looks like:

```
version: "2.1"

services:
    stockprocessor:
        image: stockprocessor
        container_name: stockprocessor
        environment:
            DATABASE_HOST: postgres-db
            DATABASE_PORT: 5432
        depends_on:
        - postgres-db
        ports:
        - 2001:2001

    postgres-db:
        image: postgres:11.1
        container_name: postgres-db
        restart: always
        environment:
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
            POSTGRES_USER: sample
            POSTGRES_DB: sample
        ports:
        - 5432:5432
```

My Spring Boot application settings are set like this:

```
spring.datasource.platform=postgres
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://${DATABASE_HOST:localhost}:${DATABASE_PORT:5432}/sample
spring.datasource.username=sample
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong, could someone help out? Thank you!

[[ Edit ]]

After analyzing the stacktrace more thoroughly, I noticed the

```
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: postgres-db
```

error, which causes the issue in the first place. After fetching the IP from the postgres-db container through

```
docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks}}{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' postgres-db
```

and setting the DATABASE_HOST to that IP, it did not work either.

More stacktrace:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The connection attempt failed.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:292) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar!/:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar!/:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:195) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar!/:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:454) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar!/:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:256) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar!/:42.2.5]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:117) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:123) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:365) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:194) ~[HikariCP-2.7.9.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:460) [HikariCP-2.7.9.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:534) [HikariCP-2.7.9.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) [HikariCP-2.7.9.jar!/:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) [HikariCP-2.7.9.jar!/:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:180) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:259) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:233) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:861) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:888) [hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) [spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) [spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) [spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) [spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) [spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758) [spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1695) [spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573) [spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) [spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) [spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) [spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) [spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1089) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:859) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:780) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1277) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1265) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at app.StockProcessorMicroservice.main(StockProcessorMicroservice.java:23) ~[classes!/:0.1.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) ~[StockProcessor.jar:0.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) ~[StockProcessor.jar:0.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) ~[StockProcessor.jar:0.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) ~[StockProcessor.jar:0.1.0]
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: postgres-db
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:70) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar!/:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:91) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar!/:42.2.5]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:192) ~[postgresql-42.2.5.jar!/:42.2.5]
    ... 59 common frames omitted

2018-11-27 16:16:44.936  WARN 1 --- [           main] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata : The connection attempt failed.
2018-11-27 16:16:44.942  WARN 1 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
2018-11-27 16:16:44.947  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2018-11-27 16:16:44.993  INFO 1 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-11-27 16:16:44.999 ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1699) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:573) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1089) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:859) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:780) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1277) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1265) [spring-boot-2.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:2.0.5.RELEASE]
    at app.StockProcessorMicroservice.main(StockProcessorMicroservice.java:23) [classes!/:0.1.0]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [StockProcessor.jar:0.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [StockProcessor.jar:0.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [StockProcessor.jar:0.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [StockProcessor.jar:0.1.0]
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:271) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:233) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:861) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:888) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) ~[spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) ~[spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1758) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1695) ~[spring-beans-5.0.9.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.9.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.determineDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:100) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.dialect.internal.DialectFactoryImpl.buildDialect(DialectFactoryImpl.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:137) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:259) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.17.Final.jar!/:5.2.17.Final]
    ... 41 common frames omitted
```

[[ Edit2 ]]

Hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost  
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback  
fe00::0 ip6-localnet  
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes  
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters  
172.19.0.2  67f456bd1ae4
```

Comment: localhost can't work; shouldn't it refer to the container IP?

Comment: username and password are not the same

Comment: Copied the wrong username, edited my post. @duffymo: I am setting the host through docker-compose to the service name, in this case postgres-db.

Answer (score 1):

That can happen if your service `stockprocessor` starts before your database is fully initialized, or during the initialization.

You must then ensure that `postgres-db` service is accepting connections before starting your application.

For that, you can use `wait-for-it.sh` script (check https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/) before running the command on your application container. Alternatively, you could set a restart policy (`restart: on-failure`) on your `stockprocessor` service (https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#restart) to automatically restart your service (until your database is up).

Comment: Hi @norbjd, I tried both solutions, but sadly none did work. While the wait script did not delayed the startup at all and the restart strategy just let the processor start over and over again, I tried to access the postgres-db container - with success. The database I wanted was already created and I was able to manipulate tables and such, all while the processor restarted over and over.

Comment: Hmm I see, just wrote this solution because 90% of issues like this are caused by startup order. Have you more info about your exception? Stacktrace, what line of code causes that, ... (edit your question). `The connection attempt failed` could be caused by 1000 reasons!

Comment: Ah yeah, I just added the whole stacktrace and I now noticed this error: `Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: postgres-db` - but localhost is not working either.

Comment: Can you check contents of `/etc/hosts` in your `stockprocessor` container (is `postgres-db` inside)?

Comment: I've added the hosts output to the original question.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue with a simple example (`image: ubuntu:14.04`, `command: ["nc", "postgres-db", "5432"]`, `restart: on-failure` replacing your `stockprocessor` service configuration). Can you try this? `stockprocessor` should then exit with a 0 exit code (it can exit with 1 first if postgres is not available but should restart until it is up).